# What is the ‘correct’ way to configure the R ‘working directory’ and ‘Project location’ in Eclipse with StatET?

Tags: eclipse, r, sweave

Unfortunately, I’m going round and round in circles when it comes to using **Sweave** in **Eclipse** with **StatET** under OS X.

If I create a project `Foo` in the default location `/Users/xxxx/Documents/workspace/Foo`, and add a Sweave file (`Foo.Rnw`), when I try to Sweave using an R Console configured with the Working Directory as `${workspace_loc}`. I get the message:

`An error occurred while running 'Processing 'Foo.Rnw'' in Workspace [R Console] R2.12_64 / RJ (Feb 26, 2011 5:58:04 PM).
Path must include project and resource name: /Foo.tex`

If I try to Sweave the same `Foo.Rnw` file (kept in the same project and the same workspace) but this time using an R console configured to use an external Working Directory (i.e. not with the `${workspace_loc}` but with `/Users/xxxx/Documents/R_data`, for example), then the file is processed and a pdf is produced. Except that all the output `Foo.aux`, `Foo.log`, `Foo.pdf`, `Foo.tex`, `Foo-fig1.eps`, `Foo-fig1.pdf` etc) appears in the external directory `/Users/xxxx/Documents/R_data`, which leads to a mess of files in one directory.

Any advice on the correct way to arrange this and to keep Sweave working in Eclipse (which I other wise like very much) would be welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use `${project_loc}` as working directory. However, before I start the R-console I have to select the eclipse-project that the R-console should use as working directory.